# when will this PostEvictionCallback be called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is my code:

```cs
public void IncrementValue(string key){

   int currentCount = _cache.Get<int>(key);

   var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
   {
       AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
   };

   options.RegisterPostEvictionCallback(UpdateDatabase);
   _cache.Set(key, currentCount + 1, options);
}
```

And **UpdateDatabase**:

```cs
private void Updatedatabase(object key, object value, EvictionReason reason, object state)
{
    int currentCount = int.Parse(value.ToString());
    _repository.AddNew(key.ToString(), currentCount);
}
```

Imagine the (first)key is created at `13:35` PM, then I update the key's value a couple times until `13:54`. When will the `UpdateDatabase` method be called ? at `14:45` or at `14:54` ?

**Edit:**

**Current question:** I can see that the expiration is overwritten each time and the AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow is being updated so it never expires, how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UpdateDatabase is called every time the `_cache.Set()` function is called, this is because the value is replaced and this will trigger the `PostEvictionCallback` . The `EvictionReason` will have the value: `Replaced`.